# Normalise a vector JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vector

I am currently trying to pass some vector tests for a module in 2D graphics I am doing.

I am currently struggling with the following test:

***Normalise function*** – your Vector object should have a ‘normalise’ function that takes no
parameters. The function should return a newly constructed Vector object that is the result of
normalising the ‘this’ Vector (making a unit Vector from it).

This is what I have done so far:

Normalise function – your Vector object should have a ‘normalise’ function that takes no
parameters. The function should return a newly constructed Vector object that is the result of
normalising the ‘this’ Vector (making a unit Vector from it).

```
 var Vector = (function () {
function Vector(pX, pY, pZ) {
    this.setX(pX);
    this.setY(pY);
    this.setZ(pZ);

}
Vector.prototype.getX = function () {
    return this.mX;
};
Vector.prototype.setX = function (pX) {
    this.mX = pX;
};
Vector.prototype.getY = function () {
    return this.mY;
};
Vector.prototype.setY = function (pY) {
    this.mY = pY;
}
Vector.prototype.getZ = function () {
    return this.mZ;
}
Vector.prototype.setZ = function (pZ) {
    this.mZ = pZ;
}

Vector.prototype.add = function (v) {
    return new Vector(this.getX() + v.getX(), this.getY() + v.getY(), this.getZ() + v.getZ());
}

Vector.prototype.subtract = function (v) {
    return new Vector(this.getX() - v.getX(), this.getY() - v.getY(), this.getZ() - v.getZ());
}

Vector.prototype.multiply = function (scalar) {
    return new Vector(this.getX() * scalar, this.getY() * scalar, this.getZ() * scalar);
};

Vector.prototype.divide = function (scalar) {
    return new Vector(this.getX() / scalar, this.getY() / scalar, this.getZ() /scalar);
};

Vector.prototype.magnitude = function () {
    return Math.sqrt(this.getX() * this.getX() + this.getY() * this.getY() + this.getZ() + this.getZ())
}


 //this is the vector I have tried for the normalisation
Vector.prototype.normalisedVector = function () {
    var vec = new Vector(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getZ());
    return new Vector(vec.divide(this.magnitude()));
}
return Vector;
 }());
```

However what I have tried isn't working and I really don't get why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

EDIT - just reading through it again, I don't think I am returning a unit vector like it asks. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Comment: `new Vector(vec.divide(this.magnitude()));` --- the `Vector` constructor accepts 3 arguments. And you're passing just one. `return this.divide(this.magnitude())` should just work.

Comment: "Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?" --- you were given at least 3 answers: one above from me and 2 below.

Comment: I mean to return it as a unit vector

Comment: The answers below just return it as a dimensional vector, i need a unit vector, I think it would be easier for me to delete this question it's getting a bit to confusing

Comment: "The answers below just return it as a dimensional vector, i need a unit vector," --- the answers below surely return a unit vector.

Comment: I thought a unit vector had a magnitude of 1

Comment: It surely does.

Comment: I'm sorry if I come across stupid to you I am new to all this, trying to work it out myself

Comment: my division function returns a vector

Comment: Well, take an arbitrary vector and apply any of the given answer. Then compare whether the returned result matches to what you expect.

Comment: "my division function returns a vector "  --- yep. And that's what you asked.

Comment: Unit vector is a vector. What does your "not a unit vector" exactly mean? How exactly the provided answers are wrong?

Comment: I was under the impression a vector had dimensions, and a unit vector had a magnitude of 1

Comment: That is correct. A unit vector has a magnitude of 1 (by definition).

Comment: I am not: I'm trying to force you to *check* your assumptions, instead of simply guessing.

Answer (score 5):

```
var vec = new Vector(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getZ());
return new Vector(vec.divide(this.magnitude()));
```

should be

```
return this.divide(this.magnitude());
```

Comment: It might be helpful to mention the previous line to that is also redundant.

Comment: @lucycopp "isn't working" is not a problem description. It is correct according to what you provided.

Comment: sorry, it is still not passing the test

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. But that is the answer for your question. Provide more context: like the initial vector value, the expected value and the actual value.

Answer (score 3):

`new Vector()` requires 3 arguments, `X`, `Y`, and `Z`. So you should divide each coordinate of the current vector by `this.magnitude()` and use those as the arguments.

```
Vector.prototype.normalizeVector = function() {
    var mag = this.magnitude();
    return new Vector(this.mX/mag, this.mY/mag, this.mZ/mag);
};
```

Comment: They have `divide` function to do exactly that actually.

Comment: yeah, didn't think of that, I was hung up on the `new Vector()` call.